# Define every natural number in $\langle N,R\rangle$ with $R:= \{(a,b); |a-b| = 1\}$

Tags: logic

I want to show that every natural number is a definable element of $\langle N,R\rangle$ with $R:= \{(a,b): |a-b| = 1\}$. An element is definable if its singleton is definable. A set $A\subseteq D$ is definable in a structure $D$ if there is a formula $\varphi(x_{1},...,x_{n})$, such that $A = \{[a_{1},...,a_{n}]; D \models \varphi[a_{1},...,a_{n}]\}$.

First, observe what elements of $R$ look like:

$(0,1)$

$(1,0)$

$(1,2)$

$(2,1)$

$\vdots$

So I got as far as being able to define 0 by the formula: $\exists y:R(x,y)\wedge\exists z:R(x,z) \rightarrow y=z$, using the fact that only 0 appears in two of those pairs, while all others appear in four (0 only appears with 1, while 1 appears with 0 an 2 and so forth). But how could I define the other natural numbers?

Comment: What is $D$ in this case?

Comment: @CameronBuie Sorry, that was a mistake and I corrected it: It should be N, the natural numbers.

Comment: Since $0$ is definable in the structure, can you define $1$ by $R(x,0)$? Then define $2$ by $x\notin\{0,1\}\wedge R(x,1)$? Etc.